# How can I make Eclipse remember the Android SDK location?

Tags: android, eclipse

Whenever I try to create a new Android project (inside an empty workspace) with Eclipse, the 'Build target' list is empty. So I need to cancel the "New Android Project" dialog, then go the preferences and re-enter the SDK location for Android.

Once I've done that, I can go back to to File -> New -> Android Project and the 'Build Target' list is full again, so I pick Android 2.1 (or whatever) and carry on with the new project.

How can I make Eclipse remember the SDK location setting, so I don't need to set it every time I want to make a new project?

For reference, I'm running Eclipse 3.6.2 with version 12 of the Android tools on Win7 x64 and I have the 32bit Android SDK installed in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk-windows`.

Comment: what is the full path to your sdk?  What version of the sdk did you install, x86 or 64?

Comment: I'm using the x86 version of the SDK, and my OS is x64

Comment: Try using "C:\Progra~2\Android\android-sdk" assuming that your SDK is installed in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk".

Comment: "How can I make Eclipse remember the SDK location setting, so I don't need to set it every time I want to make a new project?" -- this normally works, so something is *seriously* messed up in your configuration.

Comment: Are you creating a new workspace as well? That's the only time I have ever seen it not remember the SDK location.  In eclipse it kind of expects you to continue to add projects to the same workspace, you can close those projects so they don't compile etc.  This is a bit wierd if you are coming from other IDE's

Comment: @Idistic yes I am, I didn't release that's how it worked in Eclipse. My usual IDE is Visual Studio, and if I'm not using that I go for text editors & command line tools. So I'd mapped an Eclipse 'workspace' onto Visual Studio 'solution' - which explains my confusion.

Comment: @Wilka lol, had the same problem myself when I first stated using it, bit of a paradigm shift, not to bad after you get used to it though

Comment: @Idistic, if you post that as an answer, I can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you creating a new workspace as well?

That's the only time I have ever seen it not remember the SDK location. In eclipse it kind of expects you to continue to add projects to the same workspace, you can close those projects so they don't compile etc.

This is a bit wierd if you are coming from other IDE's

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was doing.